# Easy to Create Buttons in Cocos2d 2.0

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I saw a really great post about making a Button class for use in Cocos2d: http://johnehartzog.com/2009/10/easy-to-create-buttons-with-cocos2d/

I love the idea because it really simplifies button creation, but he seems to be using an older version of Cocos2d and I can't get his code working.

```
@interface Button : Menu {  // !Cannot find interface declaration for 'Menu', superclass of Button
}
+ (id)buttonWithText:(NSString*)text atPosition:(CGPoint)position target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector;
+ (id)buttonWithImage:(NSString*)file atPosition:(CGPoint)position target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector;
@end

@interface ButtonItem : MenuItem {  // !Cannot find interface declaration for 'MenuItem'...
    Sprite *back;        // !Unknown type name Sprite
    Sprite *backPressed;
}
+ (id)buttonWithText:(NSString*)text target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector;
+ (id)buttonWithImage:(NSString*)file target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector;
- (id)initWithText:(NSString*)text target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector;
- (id)initWithImage:(NSString*)file target:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector;
@end
```

Changing everything to CCMenu, CCSprite doesn't solve the problem. There are also a lot of related errors in Button.m

Is there any code similar to this that works with Cocos2d 2.0 for making simple buttons? Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backwards compatibility between different versions of Cocos2d is a tricky task. Might I recommend using [cocosbuilder](http://cocosbuilder.com) for creating menus? It has about an hour or so learning curve, but will save you many more hours down the road.

Comment: I suggest reading this cocosbuilder tutorial http://code.zynga.com/2012/10/creating-a-game-with-cocosbuilder/ It is really great tool for tedious layout routine